# Vuetify + typescript no overload matches this call error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

can`t understand what wrong in this code
my main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from '@/plugins/vue-router';
import store from '@/plugins/vuex';
import App from '@/App.vue';
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify';
import '@/plugins/ctk';
import '@/plugins/dayjs';
import VTextField from '@/components/ui/VTextField.vue';

import '@/scss/main.scss';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('VTextField', VTextField);

/* eslint-disable-next-line vue/require-name-property */
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

and console give error here

```
Vue.component('VTextField', VTextField);
                            ˆ
No overload matches this call.
Types of property 'extends' are incompatible
```

I think this is because vuetify, but can`t understand why

Thanks for tony19, update, this is my component code

```
<script>
import {
  VTextField,
} from 'vuetify/lib';

export default {
  name: 'VTextField',
  extends: VTextField,
  props: {
    hideLabel: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    showLabel() {
      return this.hasLabel && !this.hideLabel;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Where can be a problem?

Comment: Can you show `VTextField.vue`?

Comment: @tony19 this is just vuetify component https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/

Comment: Your code shows a local path for `VTextField.vue`.

Comment: @tony19 you right, i am update question